# Initital block downloading does not start

Tags: bitcoind

I've installed bitcoind as said:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt
```

Then I started server, running `bitcoind -daemon`

But initial block download doesn start for some reason. When I call `bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo` verificationprogress is always 0.0000000

On my local machine everything went well and seems that I have to fix network settings to be able to run bitcoin on remote server at collocation. But I have now Idea what to fix and where to look. I've searched google all the way up and down, I've tried `setting proxy=127.0.0.1:9050` - no effect :(

Pls help - how do I make bitcoind to connect to peers?

Comment: what does `bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo` report?

Comment: empty array '[]'

Comment: I think 8332 and 8333 ports are closed by my provider

Comment: Can you look at debug.log? Do you see it making connection attenpts at al? Do they fail or timeout?

Comment: where's that debug.log?